# Passing messages between Android activities?

Tags: android, imagebutton, message-passing

I am working on an app and need help with message passing between two screens. The first screen is a Sign-up form with an image button that is supposed to show the user's display pic. When the user first opens this screen, the ImageButton uses a "defaultavatar.png" from the drawable folder. On clicking this imagebutton, the user is directed to a screen with a GridView of icons to choose from. I need to pass the number of the image selected back to the Sign-up activity and change the source of the ImageButton's image accordingly. How do I do this? This is my code currently:

In the Sign-up activity source:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String imagePos = intent.getStringExtra(AvatarListActivity.IMAGE_NUMBER);

        //String imageName = "@drawable/bigavatar" + imagePos;
        String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        ImageButton displayPic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.displayPic);
        int imgId;

        if(imagePos != null)
        {
            imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/bigavatar"+imagePos, null, null);
            displayPic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId)); //src
        }
        else
        {
            imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/defaultavatar", null, null);
            displayPic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId)); //src
        }
```

In the Avatar List Activity:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewAvatars);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(AvatarListActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignUpActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(IMAGE_NUMBER, position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

How do I go about swapping Images depending on the user's choice?
(Note: all avatar icons have been numbered as bigavatar1, bigavatar2, bigavatar3 etc.). Please help asap and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to Android online reference: [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

> Starting Activities and Getting Results
>
> The startActivity(Intent) method is used to start a new activity,
>   which will be placed at the top of the activity stack. It takes a
>   single argument, an Intent, which describes the activity to be
>   executed.
>
> Sometimes you want to get a result back from an activity when it ends.
>   For example, you may start an activity that lets the user pick a
>   person in a list of contacts; when it ends, it returns the person that
>   was selected. To do this, you call the startActivityForResult(Intent,
>   int) version with a second integer parameter identifying the call. The
>   result will come back through your onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)
>   method.
>
> When an activity exits, it can call setResult(int) to return data back
>   to its parent. It must always supply a result code, which can be the
>   standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK, or any custom values
>   starting at RESULT_FIRST_USER. In addition, it can optionally return
>   back an Intent containing any additional data it wants. All of this
>   information appears back on the parent's Activity.onActivityResult(),
>   along with the integer identifier it originally supplied.

so you should use startActivityForResult. and bind data to intent when sending it back. you can use `bundle` to attach data.

Comment: Using startActivityForResult(intent, int) and onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) worked just fine!! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I found this page useful: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many images you have, sharedPreferences could be your bet bet.  Based on whatever image the user selects in your Avatar List, give it a number.  EX: if you have 10 images, assign each one a number.  Use sharedPreferences to import the number selection into your first activity and that will then tell it which one to display through an if statement.

Comment: It seems SharedPreferences is indeed the solution to my problem! Could you please help me with a sample code because I am unable to completely follow the syntax and code examples given on the developer sites and other blogs...